# How to add a class to edit_post_link?

Tags: posts, theme-development, links

My goal is obtain "Edit" button like this:

```
<a class="post-edit-link btn btn-default" href="{$url}">Edit this</a>
```

The first attempt I was trying adopt was adding *before* and *after* params:

```
edit_post_link( __('Edit this'), '<span class="btn btn-default">', '</span>');
```

But the result wasn't satisfying:

```
<span class="btn btn-default">
    <a class="post-edit-link" href="{$url}">Edit this</a>
</span>
```

First of all, it's redundant: I must still changing CSS to customize Edit button and there is nonsense to get more elements only to add CSS class.

Second attempt became the solution. I used *apply filter* to replace classes in string:

```
function dbj_edit_post_link($output) {
    $output = str_replace('class="post-edit-link"', 'class="post-edit-link btn btn-default"', $output);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('edit_post_link', 'dbj_edit_post_link');
```

And yes, this is what I want, but there are really no more less clunky solution to add class to "Edit" button?

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't just style the `.edit-post-link` class that's already there? That class is unique in WordPress core (i.e. it's not used by anything other than the `edit_post_link()` function. If you're using SASS or LESS you could define the `.btn` stuff as a mixin, if it's the unnecessary repetition that bothers you…

Comment: Yes, the particular reason is that I'm using Bootstrap. Indeed, there is `.edit-post-link`, but which I mentioned: this solution make additional need to change CSS. Why not using something which already exists only by adding class, without any manipulation of CSS framework core? I think this is the purpose of using framework.

Comment: Well in that case, the filter in your question is the only solution.  I agree the function isn't ideal but WordPress is an open source project that relies on people's contributions so you'd be very welcome to submit a patch if you can improve it – see https://make.wordpress.org/core/ for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try find appropriate solution to solve this issue in `edit_post_link` function and later send it to WordPress community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>*Assuming you are reading this answer in the future (December 2015 or later).*</del>

Starting from WordPress 4.4.0, The `$class` argument was added. So:

```
edit_post_link( __('Edit'), '', '', 0, 'post-edit-link btn btn-default' );
```

See [`edit_post_link` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/edit_post_link/).

Comment: Thanks for this, could not find anything on this feature in the official docs.

Comment: @Brigante I added a link to the docs.